# could not conver string to float

Tags: python

```
def check_price():
    page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

    title = soup.find(itemprop="name").get_text()
    price = soup.find(itemprop="price").get_text()
    converted_price = float(price[0:6])

    if(converted_price < 450.00):
        send_email()

    print(title.strip())
    print(converted_price)
```

hello,

my console keeps writing valueError: could not conver string to float.
thanks in advance !

Comment: The error itself is very self-explanatory. You are probably getting back a word instead of a number, and Python proceeds to shout at you for doing so.

Comment: what is your question? ... is that all the infornation? ... is there no line number mentioned?

Comment: You need to `print(title, price)` before you try the conversion.  That will tell you where the problem is.

Comment: or use a debugger, something like PyCharm, it's free!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its hard to answer this without getting more information. I'm assuming your error is on this line:

```
converted_price = float(price[0:6])
```

price[0:6] is an array. You cant convert an array to a float like that. In addition, each element may not even be a number, it could be something like this:

```
 [<a class="sister" href="http://example.com/elsie" id="link1">Elsie</a>,
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/lacie" id="link2">Lacie</a>,
  <a class="sister" href="http://example.com/tillie" id="link3">Tillie</a>]
```

Here is what I'd do. First print out price, to figure out what exactly it is.

```
print(price)
```

Now write some code to extract only the useful stuff from there. First you need to see which element you actually want, then once you find that element use substrings to get out the number. Then you can convert it to a float.

If this helps, please select this as the solution

Comment: `price` is a string and slicing a string returns another string, not an array.